# Trying to create a vimscript function that creates a new file

Tags: vim

The code I have so far is this:

```
command! -nargs=1 Nf call s:NewFile(<q-args>)<CR>

function! s:NewFile(fp)
    :echom a:fp
    :e %:h/a:fp
endfunction
```

The argument is passed in normally (I know because of the `echom` statement).

When I run a command such as: `:Nf test.py`, it echoes `test.py` as it should, but when creating the file itself, it interprets `a:fp` as the filename.

How can I get it to interpret `test.py` as the filename (or more complex filenames like `../foo/bar/test.py`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
command! -nargs=1 Nf call s:NewFile(<q-args>)

function! s:NewFile(fp)
    echom a:fp
    execute "e " . expand("%:h") . "/" . a:fp
endfunction
```

The `%:h` needs to be handed to `expand()`, so that the path is extracted from the current file. Then you need to use `execute` as the parts of the command have to be concatenated together. Then this string is executed.

Also you don't need the `<CR>` ad the end of the `command! ...`. This is only needed when you call a function (or command) from a mapping.

And the leading colons, are not needed in a script.

Comment: Thanks man! I'm still new to vimscript so your writeup helped me understand more.

Comment: @StarLlama For further Vim-related questions, you might want to join, [vi.stackexchange.com](https://vi.stackexchange.com).

Comment: For sure, didn't know about that one but will use for all vim question from now on